# Bad screen resolution on full screen apps/games ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, resolution, fullscreen

my problem started after I upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04. Any time I try to play 7 kingdoms or use WINE in full screen it gets set to an out of range screen size. How would I go about setting the resolution of a full screen app? I have an integrated GeForce 6150SE nForce 430, using the nvidia-304 driver.

```
lspci | grep VGA
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
```

I have also found other people with a similar error that says it seems to be related to SDL settings and COMPIZ.

Reinstalled ubuntu 13.10 and still when starting seven kingdoms it is set to out of range full screen resolution

Answer (score 1):

One method to stop Wine being silly in full-screen would be to use a virtual desktop to contain Wine - open 'Configure Wine', or `winecfg`, and set something like this:

[image] 
<sup>Note the 'Emulate a virtual desktop'</sup>

Wine will then run inside a Window like this:
 [image] 
<sup>Note I am not installing 7zip in wine, you can install that in Ubuntu, I am just using this as an example.</sup>

and you can tweak the size so it fits as much of the screen as it can.

I can't think of how you could stop Linux games having problems... try looking for any configuration files *(e.g. in ~/.q3a` for Urban Terror)*, and setting the screen size in those.

Comment: That will help with wine but no with the linux based games. They all start in an out of range full screen and I have been trying to figure out why for 2 days now.

Comment: I know, that is why I thought about the config files... Most of the time these are text, so are easy to set. I don't where those would be for 7 Kingdoms etc, but it saves having to struggle using the graphical over-sized interface.

Comment: I think it could be related to the compiz unity plug-in or lightdm session management. I just don't know how to get about checking a fixing

Comment: Dunno - If anything I had less of a problem is 13.10 with most games stuff, so I can't help sorry... I did find the Wine thing useful though.

Comment: yeah I'm probably just going to give up and reinstall ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. I stopped using the Nvidia driver (even though now I'm stuck at low resolution) and started using the Nouveau driver. Then my unity dash would cause PC to fail due to driver issue. Being that my graphics is out of date I thought it was because of the 3d blur effect. I then decided to give up completely on the Unity/lightDM session management and installed gnome classic.

Comment: You can disable some of the hardware acclerated stuff, either from `compizconfig-settings-manager`, Unity Tweak tool, and the Appearance settings. I moved away from Unity as ½GB of RAM, and up to 5-10% of the processor is taken *just displaying the flipping desktop*...